# Error validating geometries in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, geometry

After running the query

```
UPDATE parcel
SET wkb_geometry = ST_MakeValid(wkb_geometry) 
WHERE ST_IsValid(wkb_geometry) = 'f'
```

I receive the following error:

```
NOTICE:  Too few points in geometry component at or near point -121.78764087332524 37.700189714113364
ERROR:  Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
```

However, this is even after I imported the GeoJSON file with the `ogr2ogr` command `-nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI`, which is supposed to covert polygons to multipolygons  *and*  running

```
ALTER TABLE parcel ALTER COLUMN wkb_geometry 
    SET DATA TYPE geometry(MultiPolygon) USING ST_Multi(wkb_geometry);
```

in postgres.  What might be going wrong and how can I remove and/or alter the polygon that has too few points?

Comment: Select as WKT some geometry that can't be corrected and add it into your question.

Answer (score 2):

ST_MakeValid tries to preserve as many points as it can which means you may not get back a polygon from a malformed polygon and it will instead return a geometry collection perhaps consisting of something like a point and linestring.

What you could try is doing an ST_buffer.

```
UPDATE parcel SET wkb_geometry = ST_Multi(ST_Buffer(wkb_geometry,0))
  WHERE geometrytype(ST_multi(wkb_geometry)) != 'MULTIPOLYGON';
```

and tehn try the alter type again

Comment: Thanks.  But when I run this query I get `UPDATE 0` and then I run the update parcel query again and get the same kind of error

Comment: perhaps I should just remove the ones that are not polygons

Comment: Hmm that's odd that you get Update 0.  That would suggest they are all MULTIPOLYGON or POLYGONs already.   What does - SELECT DISTINCT geometrytype(wkb_geometry)  FROM parcel;    return?